# When and why does Gateway Metric become equal to Interface Metric ? (Windows network Adapters)

Tags: netstat, ipv4, netsh

**netsh interface ip show address .**... command reveals some information about the gateway and interface metrics of each type of adapter . However  the gateway metric seems to alwyas change and sometimes it is equal to the interface adapter metric itself ...

I would like to know the reason and how does it work ..

Note: 
I have set the interface metrics manually for each adapter